# How to create a custom Layout which will be displayed as floating element in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

I have requirement to create a component which will be displayed by the nested child component but it should not be `constrained` inside to any it's `parent` component. And I can position it like top, bottom, end, start. It's exactly like **Dialog** but more customized and I should be able to interact content behind this floating layout. Can we achieve this type of requirement in jetpack compose ??

Comment: Why is this component a child of this particular parent, if the objective is for the component to be independent of that parent from a positioning standpoint? "I should be able to interact content behind this floating layout" -- how are you defining that? IOW, could this [be a `Popup()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Popup(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties,kotlin.Function0))?

Comment: Problem with Popup is I can't show Popup any position I like

Comment: That brings us back to my original question: why is this component a child of this particular parent, if the objective is for the component to be independent of that parent from a positioning standpoint?